# AccountSet vs. FilteredAccount

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerbi

I'm trying to write my first PowerBI dashboard for CRM Online and I've got a terminology question:

When preparing CRM Reports, best practice is to use the `Filtered` views. For example `FilteredAccount`. The Filtered view merges all the Account (Base and ExtensionBase) data along with Security and Lookup and Optionset resolves.

When connecting PowerBI to CRM, I don't see any views, but I do see `Sets` similar to when doing preparing LINQ statements.

Is `AccountSet` equivalent to `FilteredAccount`?

Comment: nice question! just a note: the latest CRM versions don't have two separate tables (Base and ExtensionBase) but a single table, however it's not relevant for the question or the answer.

Comment: @GuidoPreite, thanks for the update. Didn't know that the tables had been merged. I've been using CRM Online so can't see the database tables anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, accessing any collection in the old OData endpoint or the new WebAPI endpoint is equivalent to accessing the filtered views.  That is, security and preferences such as date formatting are automatically taken into account for whichever user you are using to connect to the endpoint.

You can get optionset field labels by requesting formatted values: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx#bkmk_includeFormattedValues

Comment: Thanks! One difference I am noticing is that the OptionSet field labels aren't included in the `Set` and they are in the `FilteredView`. Is this because of the difficulty with language-localization?